# MongooseError: Model.findById() no longer accepts callback

Tags: javascript

this is the error:
MongooseError: Model.findById() no longer accepts a callback     at Function.findById (C:\Users\alexx\Desktop\proyecto\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2142:11)     at C:\Users\alexx\Desktop\proyecto\src\config\passport.js:27:10
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoveflow. Please do not post your code as an image. It makes it really hard for us to help you. Please refer to the [ask] section, in order to create a complete and answerable question.

Comment: Use the the returned promises instead. Like you already do with `User.findOne`

Answer (score 0):

In the newer version of Mongoose, findById() is no longer accepting a callback function. Instead, it returns a Query object that can be executed with .exec() and then handles the callback. Here's how you can rewrite the passport.deserializeUser function without a callback:

```
 passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findById(id);
            done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
            done(err, null);
        }
    });
```